# Sqlite3 DB is only storing the ID and not anything else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.2

ive got a problem with my database in that it only seems to be storing the id of new entries and displaying those in my form instead of the :name attribute that im asking for.  If I view the entry either using my form or via a sqlite3 browser. Only the ID is showing.

Here's my migration file..

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :detail
      t.string :more_detail
      t.string :more_details

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My form..

```
<%= form_for @client, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :detail, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :detail, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :more_detail, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :more_detail, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :more_details, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :more_details, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                clients_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And my view..

```
 ...
   <% @client.each do |client| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to client.name, client_path(client) %></td>
        <td>
      ...
```

Instead of showing the name (eg `foo`) and then a link to that clients details. It's showing me `/clients/3` and when I click on it, it's taking me to a page with empty name annd detail's fields even though they were specified when saving the entry.

If I use a sqlite3 browser. I can see the entrys have been saved but each has a `null` value for all columns except ID.

Comment: have you set attr_accessible accordingly? Please post your model code

Comment: attr_accessible? Sorry im new to Rails.

Here's my model.. pretty basic.. `class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what your problem is. The latest Rails version has attribute protection from mass assignment by default, so you need to specify which attributes you want to be accessible from outside the model like this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :name, :detail, :more_detail
end
```

Read this [section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) of the security guide.
P.S.: Did the console throw any errors when you are creating a new record?

Comment: the rails server says `SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "clients" ("created_at", "detail", "more_detail", "more_details", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 06 May 2012 18:04:01 UTC +00:00], ["detail", nil], ["more_detail", nil], ["more_details", nil], ["name", nil], ["updated_at", Sun, 06 May 2012 18:04:01 UTC +00:00]]`

Comment: Thnks but that didn't work :/ I'm wondering if the problem is in my model as I changed the create method from `:id` to `:client` and it now works.

`@client = Client.new(params[:client])`

When I try the destroy method though it says it an't find the id..

Comment: ok, so you had client.new(params[:id])? That way ActiveRecord would create a new record only with the id, like you experienced before. Show me your destroy method, post your whole controller

Comment: btw, the path to show a client should be either show_client_path(client), or directly client

Comment: Ahh ok.. it's too long to post directly but it's here - https://gist.github.com/2623738

Comment: The destroy action seems OK, how are you calling the destroy from the view?

Comment: This is with twitter bootstrap.. `<%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                      client_path(client),
                      :method => :delete,
                      :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')),
                      :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
        </td>`

Comment: I think the problem is definatly with my DB as ive stripped my view down to <h1>Listing products</h1>

`<table>
  <% @client.each do |client| %>
 
   <td class="list_description">
  <dl>
    <dt><%= client.name %></dt>
  </dl>
   </td>
 
 <td class ="list_actions">
   <%= link_to 'Show', client %><br/>
   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(client) %><br/>
   <%= link_to 'Destroy', client, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
 </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />`

But im still getting the no id error :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10941/discussion-between-bruno077-and-keva161)

Comment: I figured it out! - I changed my controller to this - https://gist.github.com/2624806 (the main line was the `format.html { redirect_to :clients` and it now works as intended.

Comment: Of course! You were trying to redirect to the non existant client. I'm glad you sorted it out. P.S: Please accept the answer as correct, because it solved your original issue =). Thanks